# Inline divs won't listen to authority

Tags: html, css, styles

I need a little bit of help disciplining my HTML. It seems to be acting up.

Anyway, the content area of a page I'm working on has two columns. To get the multi-column look, I'm **not** using one containing div for each column because some of the "rows" in the column need to be lined up.

So instead, I'm basically using several "rows" with two inline divs per row -- one for left content, one for right. Most of them are working correctly..but for some reason, my last row isn't. No matter what, it will not listen to me when I give it a width.

Here's what the relevent HTML looks like:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="topBar"></div>  //full width
    <div id="featured">                        //this "row" is working fine
        <div id="featuredVideos"></div>            //these two
        <div id="featuredLiterature"></div>        //are inline
    </div>
    <div id="browseButtons">                   //this is the "row" that is acting up
        <div id="litBrowse"></div>                 //these two
        <div id="vidBrowse"></div>                 //are inline
    </div>
</div>
```

**In the mean time**, what types of situations can cause a div to not listen to a width? I even went so far as to give every single child div inside `litbrowse` and `vidbrowse1` the same width that they have, 450px, and no dice. All of the content above it, which has essentially the exact same structure, is working fine. The only difference, maybe, is that the "row" above the row in question is comprised of two floating divs.

---

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abtFr/) showing the issue. The bottom two divs (Browse lit by category, browse vids by category)  should be spaced out, but they're scrunching together because they won't take their 450px width.

Comment: You appear to be missing a closing tag for #topBar.

Comment: @ratbum Sorry, typo when I was moving the HTML over. Nice catch. That typo isn't present in the real html.

Comment: The main thing that springs to mind is if for some reason the div didn't receive the width as you'd expect. maybe case sensitivity in CSS or incorrect selectors. Have you checked with some kind of developer tools whether the CSS thinks the width should be on the element even if it is being overriden? And is the div definitely not taking the width as opposed to the contents breaking out of the div for some reason?

Comment: @Chris That would be my thinking too, but believe me, I've quintouple-checked everything. I've played around with using a class selector for both elements, and id selectors for both individual ones..everything.

Comment: Is the div smaller or larger than it should be? Seeing this will help a lot.

Comment: @IsaacFife the jsFiddle is up now. I was going to try and get the images in there, so that's why it took a minute.

Comment: @Chris check my edit, jsfiddle is up.

Comment: @Chris the width seems to be shrinking to fit the text inside the `span`. Why? Iono.

Comment: Oh, and everybody ignore the duplicate CSS and stuff -- I've just been trying various ways to coerce these things into position, so the CSS is going to need a little bit of cleanup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are saying that `.browseBtn` is `inline`. Inline elements don't take widths, only block level elements do.

Using `inline-block` instead will do what you want. It is inline enough to make the divs side by side and block enough to allow you to specify the width.

See http://jsfiddle.net/abtFr/2/

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Sorry. Not that good an eye though. Take the class off the problem elements and it works and that leaves you with not a lot to look at to find the problem. :)

Comment: Nice catch. Working beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**SECOND EDIT** - Others have responded saying to use **display: inline-block** instead of **display: inline**.  **inline-block** is not compatible with IE7.  HOWEVER, we can make it compatible by appending

```
zoom:1;
*display: inline;
```

to the element using inline-block.  To make compatible with IE6, you need to specify a height, so add

```
_height: [yourheight]px;
```

The underscore will target IE6 only.

Alternatively you can float the elements left, in which case my original reply may be relevant.

**EDIT** - I responded without seeing the jsFiddle; this response can probably be largely ignored.

To answer your question, **floating** an element will cause it to be taken out of the normal layout.  If a div is floated left inside another div, it will be placed to the far left of that container, but its dimensions will not be taken into account when sizing that container div; in other words, that container will act like there are no divs inside.

To fix this you need to place another (empty) div inside the container, after the floating divs, and assign the style "clear: both" to it so that it will take the floating divs into account when being positioned.  In turn, the container div will see the last cleared div and resize to take it into account.

Alternatively, sometimes you can skip adding the cleared div inside the container, and just add the style "overflow: hidden" to the container itself.  This is somewhat of a hack, but a pretty robust one as far as hacks go.

Hope this solves your problem; if not we'll have to wait for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, yes, you have a `div`, but you define its `display` as `inline` (with `.browseBtn` definition). So it's not a *block-element* anymore and it doesn't listen to `width` definition.

[I've corrected the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abtFr/1/), although it might have other side effect.